# Edit not possible because of spam detection

Tags: bug, edits, spam

I tried to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41824880/1988304) (improvement of code formatting, insert image, remove chatty text):

[image: Screenshot of question]

But on "Save", I get an error message:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Whatever words I use for the beginning, I always get a message like this.

Is it because of the asian letters?